# Switch off system proxy when Fiddler core failure

Tags: c#, proxy, fiddlercore

If Fiddlercore thrown an exception then it shut down. After that system proxy settings is switched on, but proxy not defined and i need go into browser settings and manually switch off 'use proxy server' setting. Is there a way to prevent that behavior and restore system proxy to 'no proxy' manually when fiddler fails? How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a variety of strategies that you could undertake for this, but the proper fix is to not allow exceptions to bring down your process.

That means that you should be using `try`/`catch` blocks appropriately to handle exceptions rather than allowing them to kill your process.

If you're having problems with that, please share some code and I would be happy to help.